# Update Text of FlowDocument in the CodeBehind

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I need to alter the text of a `FlowDocument` without changing the existing formatting and am having trouble doing so.

My thought was to do a `foreach` of `Blocks` in the document. Then for any `Paragraph` do a `foreach` of the `Inlines` like this;

```
foreach (var x in par.Inlines)
{
    if (x.GetType() == typeof(Run))
    {
        Run r = (Run)x;
        r.Text = r.Text.Replace("@", "$");
    }
}
```

Problem is that this returns the following error message;

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution is to call ToList() on the collection and iterate through the new collection returned by ToList().

```
var runs =
    flowdoc.Blocks.OfType<Paragraph>()
    .SelectMany(par => par.Inlines).OfType<Run>()
    .ToList();

foreach (var r in runs)
{
    r.Text = r.Text.Replace("@", "$");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from trying to use the foreach loop to enumerate through a collection while also modifying the collection. Use a for loop.

For changing text in a flow document, try a TextPointer + TextRange, here's an example (this one changes the text background but you can change text just as easily).

```
private void ClearTextHighlight(FlowDocument haystack)
{
    TextPointer text = haystack.ContentStart;
    TextPointer tpnext = text.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);

    while (tpnext != null){
        TextRange txt = new TextRange(text, tpnext);
        //access text via txt.Text

        //apply changes like:
        var backgroundProp = txt.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty) as SolidColorBrush;

        if(backgroundProp != null && backgroundProp.Equals(Setting_HighlightColor)){
            //change is here
            txt.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Setting_DefaultColor);                
        }
        text = tpnext;
        tpnext = text.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);   
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit suspicious of this code, since it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett the code can run if you change the <> to !=

Comment: @Bunni This works but it does not keep the formatting

Comment: @Xaphann did you remove the example dp changing code? (All the var backGroundProp = .... to and including the clause if(backgroundProp !=)?

Comment: @GHayes honestly, I didn't need/want that background stuff so commented all that out.